# Zoom and move/drag interactive SVG in a responsive page

Tags: jquery, iframe, svg, zooming, swipe

I'm making a responsive page with a floorplan (interactive SVG). When the image is resized to the viewport, it will be too small on mobile phones. So I want the image height to be the height of the viewport, so the width will overflow.

[Link to an draft of what the page should look like](http://zandbak.copeters.nl/vh/draft.png)

I think the SVG should load in an iframe, because i'm working with a CMS (concrete5)

I tried many things, like the zoomooz plugin and the zynga scroller.. But they all interfere with the interactivity of the SVG.

I considered making the viewport user-scalable="yes", but it's not a good solution, and it conflicted with the fullscreen overlay on my page.

```js
// USED ON TEMPLATE PAGE TO RESIZE IFRAME TO DIV (VIEWPORT - DIV POSITION - MARGIN

var calcHeight = function() {
  var x = $("#viv-content");
  var position = x.position();
  $('#kaart-frame').height($(window).height() - position.top - 5);
  $('#kaart-frame').width($(window).width() - position.left - 20);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  calcHeight();
});

$(window).resize(function() {
  calcHeight();
}).load(function() {
  calcHeight();
});
```

```html
<!-- TEMPLATE IN CMS: -->

<iframe id="kaart-frame" src="URL_TO_FLOORPLAN_HTML" name="kaart-frame" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" seamless="seamless"></iframe>


<!-- FLOORPLAN HTML: -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <script>
    //this is needed to make the SVG interactive
    $.get('1e_interactief.svg', function(data) {
      //$(document.body).append(data.documentElement); // erased because i use the SVG code on the page itself
      init();


      function init() {
        //svg interactivity
        $('#markersA').click(function() {
          parent.openPopup(5);
        });
      }


      $(document).ready(function() {
        // initial scale image
        $("#svgWrapper").attr('transform', 'scale(2.5)');

        $("#svgWrapper").attr('transform', 'scale(0.9)');
      });
    });
  </script>


</head>

<body>



  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
  <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 992.1 566.9" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="svgWrapper">
      <g id="Kaart">
        <!-- SVG DATA ERASED -->
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>

</body>

</html>
```

Any ideas or examples how to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your draft I guess it can be solved without any special libraries.

Imagine a div of 600x600 in a div of 200x200 and enable overflow, it should result in a fluid experience on touch screens.

If you apply that thought on your situation, it should result in something like this:

HTML

```
<body>
    <p>Note: The width of the iframe should be the same as the width of the content in the iframe</p>

    <div id="content" class="scroll">
        <iframe id="kaart-frame" src="https://tweakers.net" name="kaart-frame" frameborder="0" noresize="noresize" width="600px"></iframe>
    </div>

    <p>Note: You can disable scrolling in the iframe by adding ' scrolling="no" '.</p>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: scroll;
    /* CSS3 */
    overflow-y: hidden;
    /* iOS */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

#kaart-frame {
    /* CSS3 */
    overflow-y: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    /* For non-touch: height: 98%; */
}
```

Check it out in this JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/w41bv8z5/5/

Note: You can still make the #content div dynamic in this example. But it is wise to let the height match with the content inside the iframe.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on iPhone and iPad: the content of the iframe is not scrollable. On desktop it works fine though.
http://zandbak.copeters.nl/vh/

Comment: On iOS it is posible that you have to add the following line to your #content CSS: 
`-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;`

Here is an updated [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w41bv8z5/4/)